# How do you access a memtable to pull to a record for edit in delphi?

Tags: delphi, dataset, ado

I know how to pull information from ADO query based on a unique ID. Is there a way to do that with a memtable, but with no unique ID to establish the record to pull for edit. Can you use just the currently selected item in the memtable?

Edit:

It is a Tkbmmemtable it is a third part component, but I assume it works similar to whatever is embedded in Delphi. Long story short, there is a form that comes up that receives data from the user. Everytime you hit ok it adds it to a tkbmmemtable (which is displayed to the user in a grid) and is stored there until you the user hits "write to database" and then it is written to a backend with a unique ID. I am trying to enable the ability to double click on a record in the grid and have a screen come up where they can edit the data and then post it back to the memtable.

Comment: What kind of "memtable" (Delphi dataset component) are you asking about, and are you planning to post the changed record back to a back-end database table via ADO?  If you are, there has to be a way to uniquely identify the record in the database table.

Comment: I added more information to my original post. The comment was too long for limits of the forum

Comment: I'm afraid your edited q is no clearer and seems self contradictory.  In the first para you say "but with no unique iD" but in the added bit you say "and then it is written to a backend **with** a unique ID".  It's a while since I used TKbmMemTable, but I don't recollect having any problem at all doing what you're asking, subject to the point about needing to be able to uniquely identify the edited record in the databse table.  A conventional ID column does that, of course, and I'm not clear why you think you can't use one.

Comment: Sorry I will try to be more clear. The unique ID is not attached to the record until the it is written to the database, while it is in the memtable there is no unique ID.

Comment: Even so, I think readers will have a hard time visualizing exactly what you have in mind because there is some key information missing, like **why** the records don't have a unique ID in the memtable.  Are they first created there, or are they read from the back-end database table?

Comment: An in-memory database works just like a regular database, except in the way it's stored (a regular database keeps its data on disk, the in-memory database stores everything in memory). So working with a MemTable is exactly like working with any other database. You don't have SQL to query the table, but you can still create indexes and use Locate or Find to get the proper record, which you can edit to your heart's content (just like any other database), and you can edit the currently selected row just like you could a regular database..

Comment: MartynA, yes they are first created there and I saw no reason until now for them to have a unique ID while in the memtable. KenWhite, That is exactly what I thought. Except I would need a unique ID in the memtable I believe to use locate or find. Unless there is another away without adding a unique ID to the memtable

Comment: No, you don't need a unique ID. Just one or more field values you can match (e.g., First name *John*, Last name *Smith*, city *Phoenix*). See the Delphi documentation for TClientDataSet, which will be very similar (if not exactly like) TkbMemTable. Or use any Delphi database tutorial that explains FindKey or Locate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you use just the currently selected item in the memtable?

The short answer is "Yes", as @KenWhite has incisively explained.

The reason the answer is "Yes" is because of the way TDataSet and its descendants like TKbmMemtable work.

Is you probably know, the defined behaviour of TDataSet et al is that it models an internal "cursor" which points to exactly one record in the dataset, and that record is treated by TDataSet and all the db-aware controls as the "active" record:  you navigate the dataset by moving the logical cursor by methods such as `First`, `Last`, `Next`, `Locate` etc.

Internally, when a TDataSet is open, it has an array of "buffers", which are pointers to dynamically allocated memory blocks which each store the data of one of a contiguous range of the records in the dataset.  The number of buffers is fixed when the dataset is opened and is determined by what db-aware components are connected to the dataset;  usually there are a sufficient number of them to hold the rows in a TDbGrid.

TDataSet has a method (function) `ActiveBuffer` which is defined in DB.Pas as

```
function TDataSet.ActiveBuffer: PChar;
begin
  Result := FBuffers[FActiveRecord];
end;
```

Any editing operation on the dataset's data operates on the record data in the `ActiveBuffer` It is identified simply by the pointer which `TDataSet.ActiveBuffer` returns.  That's all that's needed and is why editing operations on a record in an in-memory dataset work fine without any ID/PK/SequenceNumber or whatever field.

That's it, really.

Answer (score -1):

the logic would be :
 1. pull the data using adoquery
 2. put the data to memtable
 3. user will edit values
 4. save changes

treat your memtable as container. so when saving to database your code will be more like this :

```
var
script : string;
begin
  if insert then
  begin
   script :=
     'insert into table(c1, c2, c3) values (' +
      QuotedStr(memTable.FieldByName('c1').AsString) + ',' +
      QuotedStr(memTable.FieldByName('c1').AsString) + ',' +
      QuotedStr(memTable.FieldByName('c1').AsString) + ' ' +
      ')';
  end
  else
  begin
    script :=
      'update table set ' +
      'c1='+ QuotedStr(memTable.FieldByName('c1').AsString) + ',' +
      'c1='+ QuotedStr(memTable.FieldByName('c1').AsString) + ',' +
      'c1='+ QuotedStr(memTable.FieldByName('c1').AsString) + ',' +
      'where id = ' + IntToStr(memTable.FieldByName('id').AsInteger);
  end;
 // adoQuery.Execute(script);

end;
```

Comment: No.  This is not the way TKbmMemTable is intended to be used - see the demo app which comes with it.  It can stream data to and from datasets of any type (including TAdoQuery) automatically without the necessity of any script statements of the type you have shown

Comment: This is not *the logic*, and it's  not correct use of an in-memory dataset.

Comment: adoquery + memtable is already a disjointed design.. the way it was used is good a TClientDataSet or TdxMemtable..

Comment: AdoQuery * KbmMemtable is **not** a disjointed design - it is the way KbmMemTable was designed to be used.  Have you ever used it?